# Can eventvwr.msc's log files be exported to text or sql server in Windows?

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-event-log, eventviewer

Can the events from the "Event Viewer" (eventvwr.msc) in Windows (7/2003 Server/2008 Server R2) be exported to sql server or to text files?

Every search I do on Google for this returns how to export sql server integration services into sql server which isn't what I wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  While in the event viewer, choose Save As under Actions in the right pane.  You can then save them as xml, csv or text and then simply import that into SQL Server.